# private static object accessed in global space

Tags: c++, static, singleton

Singleton doubt: how am I able to access a private static object in global space? Code is given below. This runs perfectly fine.

---

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Singleton {
    static Singleton s;
    static void func()
    {
        cout<<"i am static function "<<endl;
    }
    int i;
    Singleton(int x) : i(x) {
    cout<<"inside Constructor"<<endl;
    }
    void operator=(Singleton&);
    Singleton(const Singleton&);
    public:

    static Singleton& getHandle() {
        return s;
    }
    int getValue() { return i; }
    void setValue(int x) { i = x; }
};

Singleton Singleton::s(47);


int main() {

    Singleton& s = Singleton::getHandle();
    cout << s.getValue() << endl;
    Singleton& s2 = Singleton::getHandle();
    s2.setValue(9);
    cout << s.getValue() << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any thing outside of `Singleton` accessing the private static variable `s`.

In main, you have a reference to a Singleton that **happens to be named `s`**, but this is not directly accessing the private static variable `Singleton::s`. Your method `Singleton::getHandle` returns a reference to `Singleton::s` that happens to get bound to the `s` in main, but as you demonstrate, you can bind this to something other than `s`, like `s2`.

The line

```
Singleton Singleton::s(47);
```

is defining (was well as initialing) `Singleton::s`, but if you tried to refer to `Singleton::s` inside of main, you'd get an error as expected.

Comment: so that means i can initialize static private object in global space ??

Comment: @govindparihar, It isn't really that you are "[initializing a] static private object in global space". The `Singleton Singleton::s(47);` line is defining the variable `Singleton::s`. That is, it is saying where `Singleton::s` is stored and initializing it. This becomes important when there are multiple compilation units that need to be linked together. Only one of them can define `Singleton::s`. You may want to read [What is the difference between a definition and a declaration?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410563/what-is-the-difference-between-a-definition-and-a-declaration) as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Private members are private, no matter the context. You can't access them from anywhere except from inside the class.

What you're doing is not actually accessing the private member *directly*, you use a public function to return a reference to it which can then be used. The code in the `main` function does not access the private member `m`.